# $f(x,y)= \frac{1}{y}e^{-(y+\frac{x}{y})} \text{ for } x,y > 0$ Find the marginal distribution of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> It is given that $$f(x,y) =
>  \frac{1}{y}e^{-(y+\frac{x}{y})} \text{ for } x,y > 0$$
>   Find the marginal distribution of $X$.

I can find the marginal distribution of $Y$ which is $f_{Y}(y)=e^{-y}$.
And also, the conditional distribution of $X|Y$ which is $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{1}{y} e^{-\frac{x}{y}}$.
But how to find the marginal distribution of $X$?

Answer (score 0):

Integrating out the $y$ variable, for $x>0$ we have
$$ f_X(x)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(y+\frac{x}{y})}\;\frac{dy}{y}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\sqrt{x}(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{y})}\;\frac{dy}{y}$$
and setting $t=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}$, this becomes
$$ f_X(x)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\sqrt{x}(t+\frac{1}{t})}\;\frac{dt}{t}=2K_0(2\sqrt{x})$$
for $x>0$, where
$$ K_s(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}t^se^{-\frac{x}{2}(t+\frac{1}{t})}\;\frac{dt}{t}$$
is a $K$-bessel function.

Comment: Isn't there a simple way?

Comment: This seems relatively simple to me.